# How to configure the multi tenant mongodb collection using Micronaut?

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant, micronaut, micronaut-data, mongo-collection

Im having a requirement to create mongodb collections by tenant specific.
Eg: I have a collection called audit_logs, but I want to create the following way

tenant : EAD  collection : ead_audit_logs
tenant : gtc  collection : gtc_audit_logs and so on.

somebody please help me to do the configuration in micronaut.

im using micronaut-data and the configuration to be done in the pojo/entity class is not working out.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedEntity
@Property(name = "#{@ThreadContext.get('tenant')}_audit_log")
public class AuditLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not valid because the `@Property` annotation on the class entity doesn't have any effect. To achieve the desired result, You can provide a custom implementation for the `MongoCollectionNameProvider` interface.

**Example:**

```
@Primary
@Singleton
public class CustomMongoCollectionNameProvider implements MongoCollectionNameProvider {

    @Override
    public String provide(PersistentEntity persistentEntity) {
        return String.format("%s_%s", ThreadContext.get("tenant"), persistentEntity.getPersistedName());
    }

}
```

In the above example, we have overridden the `provide` method in the `MongoCollectionNameProvider` interface. You can add your collection naming logic to this method.

And make sure to annotate the class with `@Primary` and `@Singleton`. This will ensure that the custom implementation overrides the default bean DefaultMongoCollectionNameProvider.

Comment: you made my day. it is working as expected, thank you so much. much appreciated